# RSA SecurID for Android : CryptoException code 100 when calling MfaSecureId.GetInstance

Tags: android, rsa, securid

I am using the 3.0.1 RSASecureID SDK for iOS and for Android.

I have successfully implemented the iOS part and have been able to get a OTP from a CTF string and password.

For Android, I get the following exception when calling the MfaSecureId.GetInstance method.

```
com.rsa.mfasecuridlib.exception.CryptoException: 100
at com.rsa.mfasecuridlib.internal.f.u.cc(Unknown Source:120)
at com.rsa.mfasecuridlib.MfaSecurID.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
at com.rsa.mfasecuridlib.MfaSecurID.getInstance(Unknown Source:9)
```

I'm looking for some help or documentation about the exceptions code to be able to understand the origin of my issue and solve it.

I've follow the documentation found [here](https://community.rsa.com/t5/securid-sdk-documentation/securid-sdk-3-1-for-android-developer-s-guide-and-release-notes/ta-p/626188) but I'm still stucked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code 100 means that the file "jcmandroidfips.raw" is not found in the ressources folder (raw) of the Android application project.